# I need to link Google Sheet with my Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-sheets-api

i want to link my laravel app with Google sheet i use this package :

[Google Sheets API v4 for Laravel](https://github.com/kawax/laravel-google-sheets)

my function  :

```
  public function doPostData(){

        $append = [
           'name',
           'email@email.com',
            'joe',
        ];

        Sheets::spreadsheet('1A5NSRIVN_uSBI2JcoJPNc7N0rvHL-dmIrg9_jgESscA')
              ->sheet('YouCan')
              ->append([$append]);

    }
```

i get this error :

```
array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
```

```
  private function fetchToken()

    {

        $auth_tokens = $this->fetcher->fetchAuthToken($this->httpHandler);

 

        if (array_key_exists('access_token', $auth_tokens)) {

            // notify the callback if applicable

            if ($this->tokenCallback) {

                call_user_func(

                    $this->tokenCallback,

                    $this->fetcher->getCacheKey(),

                    $auth_tokens['access_token']

                );

            }

 

            return $auth_tokens['access_token'];
```

my env file :

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_NAME=
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=
GOOGLE_REDIRECT=
GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_KEY=
GOOGLE_SERVICE_ENABLED=true
GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_LOCATION=../storage/credentials.json
```

Note : i create the Service Accounts + OAuth Id and i shared the file

Comment: As per the error you are getting,```$auth_tokens``` (parameter 2 of ```array_key_exists()```) has to be an array and it is not. What is the output you get from ```var_dump($auth_tokens);```??

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me :

ErrorException
array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
C:\laragon\www\wonood\vendor\google\auth\src\Middleware\AuthTokenMiddleware.php:124

My controller ↓

```
<?php
    
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
use Revolution\Google\Sheets\Facades\Sheets;
    
class MagicViewController extends Controller
{
  public function google()
  {
    
    
  // Add new sheet to the configured google spreadsheet
  Sheets::spreadsheet('19eKwKwxxxKsd6cSM')->addSheet('sheet 3');
    
    
  $rows = [
  ['1', '2', '3'],
  ['4', '5', '6'],
  ['7', '8', '9'],
  ];
    
    
  // Append multiple rows at once
  Sheets::sheet('sheetTitle')->append($rows);
    
return view('magic_view');
    
  } 
}
```

My .env ↓

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_NAME=MyApp
SPREADSHEET_ID=19eKwKwM0wGhXXXXXXXXXd6cSM
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=2410oksuct.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=XXXXXXXXX3IFqwVsd7kYFXXXbWd
GOOGLE_REDIRECT=
GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_KEY=
GOOGLE_SERVICE_ENABLED=true
GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_LOCATION=./storage/credentials.json
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./storage/credentials.json
```

My google config in /config/google.php ↓

```
<?php

return [
    /*
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Google application name
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'application_name' => env('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_NAME', 'MyApp'),

    /*
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Google OAuth 2.0 access
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Keys for OAuth 2.0 access, see the API console at
    | https://developers.google.com/console
    |
    */
    'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', '2410oksuct.apps.googleusercontent.com'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET', 'XXXXXXXXX3IFqwVsd7kYFXXXbWd'),
    'redirect_uri' => env('GOOGLE_REDIRECT', ''),
    'scopes' => [],
    'access_type' => 'online',
    'approval_prompt' => 'auto',

    /*
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Google developer key
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Simple API access key, also from the API console. Ensure you get
    | a Server key, and not a Browser key.
    |
    */
    'developer_key' => env('GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_KEY', ''),

    /*
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Google service account
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Set the credentials JSON's location to use assert credentials, otherwise
    | app engine or compute engine will be used.
    |
    */
    'service' => [
        /*
        | Enable service account auth or not.
        */
        'enable' => env('GOOGLE_SERVICE_ENABLED', false),

        /*
         * Path to service account json file. You can also pass the credentials as an array
         * instead of a file path.
         */
        'file' => env('GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_LOCATION', './storage/credentials.json'),
    ],

    /*
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Additional config for the Google Client
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Set any additional config variables supported by the Google Client
    | Details can be found here:
    | https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php
    |
    | NOTE: If client id is specified here, it will get over written by the one above.
    |
    */
    'config' => [

        'spreadsheet_id'=> '19eKwKwM0wGhXXXXXXXXXd6cSM',
        // 'google_application_credentials'=> './storage/credentials.json',
    ],
];
```

**Note :**

- I share spreadsheet with my google service account mail : laravel@myApp.iam.gserviceaccount.com
- Drive and Sheet API are actived
- OAuth is actived

I work on development with :
laragon -
Php 7.2.19 -
Laravel Framework 7.28.4

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and I solved it by the following solution

in config/google in the set scope as

scope=>[\Google_Service_Sheets::DRIVE, \Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

1 -  [Google Api Client package](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)

2 - enable the google sheets api and create credentials :

[Google Developer console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?hl=ar)

After installing and configure your API :

3 -  Create a new a Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;


use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_Sheets;
use Google_Service_Drive ;
use Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange;
use App\Models\Api\SheetAuth as ApiSheetAuth;
use App\Models\Colis;
use Google\Service\ServiceControl\Auth;
use App\Models\TemplateFields;
use App\Http\Controllers\callcenter\DispatchCallsController as CallCenter;

class GoogleSheet
{
    private $spreadSheetId;

    private $client;

    public $googleSheetService;

    public function __construct()
    {
       // $this->spreadSheetId = config('datastudio.google_sheet_id');

        $this->client = new Google_Client();
        $this->client->setAuthConfig(storage_path('credentials.json'));
        $this->client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets");

        

        $this->googleSheetService = new Google_Service_Sheets($this->client);
    }
```